# Is there a way to invoke Gmaps4rails.geocode(address) from within javascript?

Tags: javascript, gmaps4rails

I would like to do something like this in javascript:

```
var latLngMatches = Gmaps4rails.geocode(address);
...
```

This does not work inside embedded javascript.  In fact, if
I go into the Chrome console and type `Gmaps4Rails`, the
object in javascript does not have a function `geocode` (see further below).

Question:  is there a way to invoke `Gmaps4rails.geocode(address)`
from within javascript?

JAVASCRIPT CONSOLE output:

```
function Gmaps4Rails() {
      this.map = null;
      this.visibleInfoWindow = null;
      this.userLocation = null;
      this.geolocationFailure = function() {
        return false;
      };
      this.callback = function() {
        return false;
      };
      this.customClusterer = function() {
        return false;
      };
      this.infobox = function() {
        return false;
      };
      this.jsTemplate = false;
      this.default_map_options = {
        id: 'map',
        draggable: true,
        detect_location: false,
        center_on_user: false,
        center_latitude: 0,
        center_longitude: 0,
        zoom: 7,
        maxZoom: null,
        minZoom: null,
        auto_adjust: true,
        auto_zoom: true,
        bounds: [],
        raw: {}
      };
      this.default_markers_conf = {
        title: "",
        picture: "",
        width: 22,
        length: 32,
        draggable: false,
        do_clustering: false,
        randomize: false,
        max_random_distance: 100,
        list_container: null,
        offset: 0,
        raw: {}
      };
      this.markers = [];
      this.boundsObject = null;
      this.polygons = [];
      this.polylines = [];
      this.circles = [];
      this.markerClusterer = null;
      this.markerImages = [];
    }
```

Comment: If the function doesn't exist, there is no way for you to invoke it.

Comment: It doesn't exist at the javascript level, but it is documented for the Ruby api (see https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Methods).  I'm curious to know what the author had in mind for javascript usage.

Comment: I see. Unless the same method is exposed in the JavaScript solution, you would need to fire off a request to the server to retrieve that data.

Comment: It's so simple to query the google maps geocoding api in js that I can't see any added value to wrap it. See an example here: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: Thanks. That worked.  I guess my inclination would be to have a single api through which all GMap queries are made.  I don't know know enough about what internal state is maintained in gmap4rails, so I try to avoid making out-of-band queries.